# How to get texture offset from material in three.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d, textures, texture-mapping, collada

we are loading a DAE model in three.js and we want to get the exact position of the texture image within the face for a particular face.

For example, let's say that the face is rectangular like this:
[image]

And the texture image used is like this:
[image]

We want to know the size and position of the red rectangle relative to the texture image:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: It would be great if you could accept and upvote my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You should change the UV mapping on the material, it can help "offset" the material. Three.js currently doesn't have high support for offsetting, so these are the two things you could do:

1. `UV Mapping`, like I said, or:
2. `Change the positioning of the texture`, until you get the desired amount.